# Testing multiple components in angular 2

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx

I have a variable v1 inside component1 and v2 in component2.whenever v1 changes v2 gets changed.
I would like to write a test case for above case, but don't understand How to write it,since in unittests we consider only one component each time.
My variables are depending through ngrx store, whenever v1 changes it triggers an action and my variable v2 changes each time an action is triggered.
Should I write a unit-test or an e2e test?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably write both unit tests and e2e tests.

For your unit tests you would have 3 separate sets of unit tests.  One for your first component, one for your second component, and one for the ngrx reducer.

Finally to test that the whole thing integrates well together write the e2e test.  But the e2e test won't be testing a variable change.  It would have to be testing some dom changes of some sort.

So I'm assuming that v2 is somehow used to display something on the dom.  If it's not doing anything visible to the dom then the unit tests should be enough.

Comment: So I would like to know how would you deal with the code coverage in this case since e2e won't increase the coverage

Comment: The three unit tests would increase code coverage.  That said, I think e2e tests are more valuable than unit tests if you really want to confirm that something is working.  Also if you really care about code coverage you can write your unit tests as integration tests.  Angular definitely allows you to render all the child components and use real services.  The only thing is that it's a pain to write these types of tests.  It's a lot easier to use something like Cypress to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... why would you want to test ngrx behaviour? You should probably have test cases that test your component when variable is in default state and when it's modified.